# ioredis connection keeps resetting when connecting to local redis cluster from docker container

Tags: node.js, networking, docker-compose, redis, ioredis

I have a docker compose containerized client/server node app that is failing to create a stable connection to a redis cluster I have running on my local environment. The redis cluster has 6 nodes (3 master, 3 replica configuration) running on my local machine. Every time I start my app and attempt to connect to redis, the `connect` event is spammed and I get the following error on my client:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /check-login from localhost:3000 to http://server.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET)
```

I have made sure to configure the redis cluster to have the settings `protected-mode` to `no` and `bind` to `0.0.0.0` to allow remote access to the cluster. I have confirmed that I can access the cluster locally by pinging one of the cluster nodes `redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 30001`:

```
127.0.0.1:30001> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:30001> exit
```

I am setting my `REDIS_HOSTS` environment to be `"host.docker.internal:30001,host.docker.internal:30005,host.docker.internal:30006"`. This should allow me to connect to my redis cluster running at `127.0.0.1` on my host machine. My node application code:

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");

const hosts = process.env.REDIS_HOSTS.split(",").map((connection) => {
  const [host, port] = connection.split(":");

  return {
    host,
    port,
  };
});

const client = new Redis.Cluster(hosts, {
  enableAutoPipelining: true,
  slotsRefreshTimeout: 100000,
});

client.on("error", (error) => {
  console.log("redis connection failed: ", error);
});

client.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("redis connection established");
});

module.exports = client;
```

My ioredis logs:

```
2022-02-11T23:52:09.970Z ioredis:cluster status: [empty] -> connecting
info: Listening on port 80
2022-02-11T23:52:15.449Z ioredis:cluster resolved hostname host.docker.internal to IP 192.168.65.2
2022-02-11T23:52:15.476Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Reset with [
  { host: '192.168.65.2', port: 30001 },
  { host: '192.168.65.2', port: 30002 },
  { host: '192.168.65.2', port: 30003 }
]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.482Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 192.168.65.2:30001 as master
2022-02-11T23:52:15.504Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30001]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.511Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 192.168.65.2:30002 as master
2022-02-11T23:52:15.517Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30002]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.519Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 192.168.65.2:30003 as master
2022-02-11T23:52:15.521Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30003]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.530Z ioredis:cluster getting slot cache from 192.168.65.2:30002
2022-02-11T23:52:15.541Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.590Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: wait -> connecting
2022-02-11T23:52:15.603Z ioredis:redis queue command[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: 0 -> cluster([ 'slots' ])
2022-02-11T23:52:15.614Z ioredis:cluster:subscriber selected a subscriber 192.168.65.2:30001
2022-02-11T23:52:15.621Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30001 (ioredis-cluster(subscriber))]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.622Z ioredis:cluster:subscriber started
2022-02-11T23:52:15.734Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: connecting -> connect
2022-02-11T23:52:15.737Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: connect -> ready
2022-02-11T23:52:15.739Z ioredis:connection set the connection name [ioredis-cluster(refresher)]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.742Z ioredis:redis write command[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: 0 -> client([ 'setname', 'ioredis-cluster(refresher)' ])
2022-02-11T23:52:15.749Z ioredis:connection send 1 commands in offline queue
2022-02-11T23:52:15.750Z ioredis:redis write command[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: 0 -> cluster([ 'slots' ])
2022-02-11T23:52:15.781Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result count: 3
2022-02-11T23:52:15.783Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result [0]: slots 0~5460 served by [ '127.0.0.1:30001', '127.0.0.1:30004' ]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.788Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result [1]: slots 5461~10922 served by [ '127.0.0.1:30002', '127.0.0.1:30005' ]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.792Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result [2]: slots 10923~16383 served by [ '127.0.0.1:30003', '127.0.0.1:30006' ]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.849Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Reset with [
  { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 30001, readOnly: false },
  { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 30004, readOnly: true },
  { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 30002, readOnly: false },
  { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 30005, readOnly: true },
  { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 30003, readOnly: false },
  { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 30006, readOnly: true }
]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.850Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Disconnect 192.168.65.2:30001 because the node does not hold any slot
2022-02-11T23:52:15.851Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30001]: wait -> close
2022-02-11T23:52:15.851Z ioredis:connection skip reconnecting since the connection is manually closed.
2022-02-11T23:52:15.852Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30001]: close -> end
2022-02-11T23:52:15.857Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Remove 192.168.65.2:30001 from the pool
2022-02-11T23:52:15.858Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Disconnect 192.168.65.2:30002 because the node does not hold any slot
2022-02-11T23:52:15.858Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30002]: wait -> close
2022-02-11T23:52:15.859Z ioredis:connection skip reconnecting since the connection is manually closed.
2022-02-11T23:52:15.859Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30002]: close -> end
2022-02-11T23:52:15.861Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Remove 192.168.65.2:30002 from the pool
2022-02-11T23:52:15.861Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Disconnect 192.168.65.2:30003 because the node does not hold any slot
2022-02-11T23:52:15.861Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30003]: wait -> close
2022-02-11T23:52:15.865Z ioredis:connection skip reconnecting since the connection is manually closed.
2022-02-11T23:52:15.866Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30003]: close -> end
2022-02-11T23:52:15.866Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Remove 192.168.65.2:30003 from the pool
2022-02-11T23:52:15.867Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 127.0.0.1:30001 as master
2022-02-11T23:52:15.869Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30001]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.871Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 127.0.0.1:30004 as slave
2022-02-11T23:52:15.873Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30004]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.874Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 127.0.0.1:30002 as master
2022-02-11T23:52:15.877Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30002]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.877Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 127.0.0.1:30005 as slave
2022-02-11T23:52:15.882Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30005]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.883Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 127.0.0.1:30003 as master
2022-02-11T23:52:15.885Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30003]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.886Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Connecting to 127.0.0.1:30006 as slave
2022-02-11T23:52:15.887Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30006]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:15.893Z ioredis:cluster status: connecting -> connect
2022-02-11T23:52:15.904Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30002]: wait -> connecting
2022-02-11T23:52:15.906Z ioredis:redis queue command[127.0.0.1:30002]: 0 -> cluster([ 'info' ])
2022-02-11T23:52:15.916Z ioredis:cluster:subscriber subscriber has left, selecting a new one...
2022-02-11T23:52:15.917Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30001 (ioredis-cluster(subscriber))]: wait -> close
2022-02-11T23:52:15.918Z ioredis:connection skip reconnecting since the connection is manually closed.
2022-02-11T23:52:15.918Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.65.2:30001 (ioredis-cluster(subscriber))]: close -> end
2022-02-11T23:52:15.919Z ioredis:cluster:subscriber selected a subscriber 127.0.0.1:30004
2022-02-11T23:52:15.921Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30004 (ioredis-cluster(subscriber))]: [empty] -> wait
2022-02-11T23:52:16.000Z ioredis:connection error: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30002
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16)
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 30002 }
2022-02-11T23:52:16.030Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30002]: connecting -> close
2022-02-11T23:52:16.031Z ioredis:connection skip reconnecting because `retryStrategy` is not a function
2022-02-11T23:52:16.032Z ioredis:redis status[127.0.0.1:30002]: close -> end
2022-02-11T23:52:16.034Z ioredis:cluster:connectionPool Remove 127.0.0.1:30002 from the pool
2022-02-11T23:52:16.036Z ioredis:cluster Ready check failed (Error: Connection is closed.
    at close (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:184:25)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/ioredis/built/redis/event_handler.js:155:20)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:520:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:675:12)). Reconnecting...
2022-02-11T23:52:16.042Z ioredis:cluster status: connect -> disconnecting
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The clue to the solution was found in the following log snippet:

```
2022-02-11T23:52:15.750Z ioredis:redis write command[192.168.65.2:30002 (ioredis-cluster(refresher))]: 0 -> cluster([ 'slots' ])
2022-02-11T23:52:15.781Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result count: 3
2022-02-11T23:52:15.783Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result [0]: slots 0~5460 served by [ '127.0.0.1:30001', '127.0.0.1:30004' ]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.788Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result [1]: slots 5461~10922 served by [ '127.0.0.1:30002', '127.0.0.1:30005' ]
2022-02-11T23:52:15.792Z ioredis:cluster cluster slots result [2]: slots 10923~16383 served by [ '127.0.0.1:30003', '127.0.0.1:30006' ]
```

The internal redis cluster network was still communicating between nodes on network address `127.0.0.1`, creating the `connect ECONNREFUSED` errors when the `ioredis` client attempted to use those network mappings to establish the cluster connection.

I had to use the `natMap` option in the `ioredis` client to remap the internal cluster network connections to the network address of the docker container:

```
let natMap = {};
const localHost = "127.0.0.1";

const hosts = process.env.REDIS_HOSTS.split(",").map((connection) => {
  const [host, port] = connection.split(":");

  // assign nat host address mappings
  // when accessing local redis cluster from containerized network
  natMap[`${localHost}:${port}`] = { host, port };

  return {
    host,
    port,
  };
});

// natMap output
// {
//   "127.0.0.1:30001": { host: "docker.internal.network", port: 30001 },
//   "127.0.0.1:30002": { host: "docker.internal.network", port: 30002 },
//   "127.0.0.1:30003": { host: "docker.internal.network", port: 30003 },
// }

// create redis cluster client
const client = new Redis.Cluster(hosts, {
  enableAutoPipelining: true,
  slotsRefreshTimeout: 100000,
  natMap,
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was missing this natMap option all along

Comment: How do you configure that natmap? I mean, im using Elasticache and have the node address and the "cfg" address. Which one goes where?

Comment: Works perfectly!